# Website Publish Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, publish

I have a Web Application consuming a WebService. My web application has 2 projects - Startup and Other projects. I am able to build my solution and also run it without any problem in my local machine.

My Other project has a dll referenced named [crypto](http://www.dll-downloader.net/c/crypto-dll/). It is strongly named dll. Now I trying to publish my web app using File System. However it fails. Following are the errors.

`The type or namespace name crypto could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)`

From my output window

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "crypto". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`

And finally it skips the Publish of website. Could anyone suggest me whats going on? Similarly I even had an `WPF` app and I was facing similar issue in Strongly Named dlls while creating Setup file. There I just put all the dlls in Special GAC folder and things worked. Here I am not sure.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that one machine is running 32-bit and one is running 64-bit?  If the dll is x86 dependent or vice versa, that could cause an issue like this if the application is compiled as Any CPU config.

Comment: Your suggestion is not working....

Comment: remove crypto dll from your projects, and add reference again ,and be sure that crypto that you upload is exactly same as one you adding in reference.and then upload your projects dll again.

Comment: @minamorsali: You have to accept BEER from me. Your address....Well great solution and it worked. Was troubling me from morning. Could you please post this as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you, yes,I post it now :) .I'm glad that my answer solved your problem. I before have same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove crypto dll from your projects, and add reference again , and be sure that crypto that you upload is exactly same as one you adding in reference. and then upload your project's dll again.